# How to set button background image size

Tags: ios, swift, background, uibutton, uiimage

I want to create [this](http://oi62.tinypic.com/ma8cuq.jpg) button in my application. I have added a button to my view in storyboard. Set it's width and height constraints to 60px.

Then in code I've added corner radius and UIImage to background but the image filled the whole button background. The image is 22x22px. I want it to be centered in button like on my screenshot.

```
var pencilImage = UIImage(named: "pencil")!
pencilBtn.setBackgroundImage(pencilImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
pencilBtn.layer.cornerRadius = pencilBtn.frame.size.height / 2
pencilBtn.clipsToBounds = true
```

What should I code to solve this?

Comment: Can you post, what result you get?

Comment: instead of setting the background image set it as image directly with content mode set to 'center'

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr [Here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/308fywi.jpg) it is.

Comment: @lukya Did you mean this code `pencilBtn.imageView!.image = pencilImage
        pencilBtn.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center` ? It doesn't work(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set image using `.setImage()` method Like this:

```
pencilBtn.layer.cornerRadius = pencilBtn.frame.size.height / 2
pencilBtn.clipsToBounds = true   
pencilBtn.setImage(UIImage("pencil"), forState: .Normal)
pencilBtn.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and also the lukya's comment is correct.